# popoverView error trying to load UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to create a popup camera view however I am getting this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController _commonPresentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

I am calling my cameraViewController like this

```
- (void) cameraButtonSelected
{
    CameraViewController *cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];
    cameraViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 150.0);
    [self.view addSubview:cameraViewController.view];
}
```

And this is the ViewController viewDidLoad method I have tried to create

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(self.view.window!=nil)
        [objPopView presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    objPopView = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [objPopView presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(842, 163, 0, 0)
                                inView:self.view
              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight
                              animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems.

- You are doing this too early. `viewDidLoad` means your view is *not* yet in the window. It just means that the view exists. Wait until `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` to do this. That is the sign that the view is now in the interface. You might have to use a condition so as to do it only the first time.
- This code is really weird:

  ```
  if(self.view.window!=nil)
      [objPopView presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  ```

  You have not yet defined `objPopView`, plus if this condition is met you will do this presentation of the popover and then go right on and do *another* presentation of the popover.